# Activity tracking when not wearing Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, ios, activity-monitor, activity.app

Once in a while, I eschew my Apple Watch in favor of something else. On those days, I have no tracking of activities. However, iPhone supports at least some activity tracking on its own (specifically steps). Is it possible to have my iPhone track activities when I'm not wearing my Apple Watch?

Comment: Related documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph9a08e004e/ios and https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/apd3bf6d85a6/watchos

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the same sensors, not officially. You've already observed what the iPhone does record.

If you want to, for example, go for a run, you can use a 3rd party app (such as Strava [no endorsement, just an example]) that will record GPS data and record a workout to Health & the Fitness app.

There is no solution to record "Workout Minutes," etc. without wearing the Watch.

Comment: iPhone is able to automatically track activity though, as per their official documentation; https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph9a08e004e/ios

Comment: Yes, this is true. I was very careful not to mention Active Energy because of this. However, looking in my Health database my phone hasn't recorded any Active Energy in the last 8 months recently despite the fact I do occasionally have my watch charging when I go outside with my phone so I'm unsure if this is recommended for people with watches to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

You get steps and flights of stairs climbed only with iPhone and iOS 17. No activities, no workouts, no heart rate and other watch specific data is generated or shown in either health or the fitness app.

You will want to install third party apps to work out with your phone and get some of the functionality that Apple Watch delivers for fitness and activity tracking.